# Debugging Hikari Pool connections in Spring Boot Application - See any identifier of each connection of the pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot application, where I have created a class which implements **DelegatingDataSource**. I use **Hikari pool**, and I have DEBUG level on their packages. I'm facing some errors related to processes which try to execute a query, but it fails because the connection is closed. If I debug the API call, I never find the error, so any concurrency error should exist.

I would like to see if there is any way of **printing any identifier of the connection pool**. I mean, I have configured a pool size of 50, and if I run the application I have some logs like this (x50 times):

```
... [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : tenantDataSource - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6214982
```

If, once the application starts, I debug into a connection object, it doesn't have the same hashcode of any of the connection pool. So, my main question is: **Is there any way to print an ID or something similar in order to identify the connection of the pool I'm using?** I would expect something like:

```
Connection connection = getTargetDataSource().getConnection();
log.info("I have the connection with ID" + connection.getSomeIdentifier());
```

If I have this log, I would be able to debug in staging environment, so I can find if any process are closing a connection which is used by other thread/process in parallel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your DataSource bean is properly configured to use HikariCP as the connection pool:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
      // Configure Hikari pool properties, such as database URL, username, password, etc.
      return dataSource;
  }
}
```

Use the `@Scope("prototype")` annotation on the connection handling class to create a new instance for each thread:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ConnectionHandler {

  private Connection connection;

  public void openConnection() {
      // Logic to open the database connection
      // Use the DataSource to acquire a connection
      this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
  }

  public void closeConnection() {
      // Logic to close the database connection
      if (this.connection != null) {
          try {
              this.connection.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              // Handle connection closing exception if necessary
          }
      }
  }

// Methods to handle the connection
}
```

Use the `ThreadLocal` class to ensure that each thread gets its own instance of the `ConnectionHandler`:

```
@Component
public class ConnectionHandlerProvider {
  private ThreadLocal<ConnectionHandler> connectionHandlerThreadLocal = 
  new ThreadLocal<>();

  public ConnectionHandler getConnectionHandler() {
      ConnectionHandler connectionHandler = 
  connectionHandlerThreadLocal.get();
      if (connectionHandler == null) {
          connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler();
          connectionHandler.openConnection();
          connectionHandlerThreadLocal.set(connectionHandler);
      }
      return connectionHandler;
  }

  public void releaseConnectionHandler() {
      ConnectionHandler connectionHandler = 
  connectionHandlerThreadLocal.get();
      if (connectionHandler != null) {
          connectionHandler.closeConnection();
          connectionHandlerThreadLocal.remove();
      }
  }
}
```

When using the `ConnectionHandler`, obtain the instance from the `ConnectionHandlerProvider` and ensure that it is released after use:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private ConnectionHandlerProvider connectionHandlerProvider;

  public void doSomethingWithConnection() {
      ConnectionHandler connectionHandler = 
  connectionHandlerProvider.getConnectionHandler();
      try {
          // Use the connection to execute queries or perform database 
  operations
      } finally {
          connectionHandlerProvider.releaseConnectionHandle();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a very similar configuration that the one you mention, but what I want is to be able to print an identifier, because there are some unknown errors I would like to debug